# Where can I find a powershell script that created full SharePoint 2010 site hierarchy based on an XML file?

Tags: powershell

Hi
I am trying to create a powershell script to automate the creation of a SP2010 site collection.
I want to have an XML file that the script can use to create the top site, sub sites, Lists, etc.

Something like

```
    <Setup>
  <Sites>
    <TopSite>
      <Name>Site1</Name>
    </TopSite>
  </Sites>
  <Sites>
    <TopSite>
      <Name>Site2</Name>
      <Lists>
        <List>
          <Name>List1</Name>
          <Field>
            <Name>TestColumn1</Name>
            <Type>Text</Type>
          </Field>
          <Field>
            <Name>TestColumn2</Name>
            <Type>Text</Type>
          </Field>
          <Field>
            <Name>TestColumn3</Name>
            <Type>Text</Type>
          </Field>
          <Field>
            <Name>TestColumn4</Name>
            <Type>Text</Type>
          </Field>
        </List>
      </Lists>
    </TopSite>
    <SubSite>
      <Name>Subsite2a</Name>
      <Lists>
        <List>
        <List>
          <Name>List1</Name>
          <Field>
            <Name>TestColumn1</Name>
            <Type>Text</Type>
          </Field>
          <Field>
            <Name>TestColumn2</Name>
            <Type>Text</Type>
          </Field>
          <Field>
            <Name>TestColumn3</Name>
            <Type>Text</Type>
          </Field>
          <Field>
            <Name>TestColumn4</Name>
            <Type>Text</Type>
          </Field>
        </List>
      </Lists>
    </SubSite>
  </Sites>
</Setup>
```

IS there some ready script that I can use for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this useful script.

http://www.sharepointedutech.com/2010/02/12/create-sharepoint-2010-sites-using-powershell-reading-an-xml-file/